# Finding the Sum of a String of numbers seperated by operators

Tags: java

Given String = "128+16+8+2+1"
Answer should print out 155

The code is supposed to add all numbers in the string and the answer should be printed out as a string.
I attempted to write the code for this, however the last 2 numbers will not add and my current answer is printing out 153. Looking for help to lead me to the correct solution.

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class add {
    static void evalA(String s) {
        int n = countChar(s,'+');
        System.out.println(s);
        int cnt = 0;
        int[] data = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i)=='+') {
                System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));
                data [cnt] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,i));
                cnt++;
                s = s.substring(i+1,s.length()-1);
               i=0;
            }

        }
        String sum = ""+IntStream.of(data).sum();
        System.out.println(sum); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\+").splitAsStream(s).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()`

Comment: @shmosel That could be an answer :-)

Comment: I don't quite understand that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    evaluate("128+16+8+2+1");
}

public static void evaluate(String equation)
{
    String[] numbers = equation.split("\\+");

    int sum = 0;

    for (String number : numbers)
    {
        //could wrap this in a check incase of exception or errors
        sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

It just splits the string up by the `+` to get the individual numbers as an array and then loop through the array and add each numbers value to a sum variable.